# Background images and pop up related issue in live

Tags: wordpress, image, file-upload, popup, custom-wordpress-pages

I have developed a WordPress site in local successfully. But I am facing an issue while I uploaded WordPress all files from local host to server to go live. The issues which I have faced are following- 1. in live website homepage's background images are not showing including pop ups(but working perfectly in local) 2. If I search my website (live) in google I can find everything is perfect but if I change the device (other than the device from where I've uploaded all the files) and search for my website , there the few background images (Not all) and all the pop up images are not showing (in Live).

Kindly tell me the solution. I am wordpress developer (Beginner) and no idea of coding.

1. From the guidance from internet I tried to change the permission of wp-upload files but changes are not made.
2. I have tried to do image optimizing which I found not a positive step.